# How do I tell a page to use a different PHP file in Joomla

Tags: php, templates, joomla

So basically I have a template that I use for every single page besides one page - The gallery page - I want it to look a different way therefore I have to take some of the code out of the .php file, but obviously I don't want to take it out of the index.php because that will affect all the pages then.

My question is basically how do I tell the Gallery page (Menu item) to use this different .php file - gallery.php - Much like how in WordPress you can have different .php files for pages.

I know that you are supposed to use the template manager to "Assign" menu items to different templates but how does it know what file to reference for the separate template. Do you have to create another folder on your server that would contain a different index.php?

Comment: what version of Joomla! are you using?

(don't worry just saw the reference to Style's in the comments)

Answer (score 2):

No need to create another folder or index.php

All you need is to assign a different template for the menu item for your Gallery page.

Go to Joomla administration, select `Menus` from the top menu in admin, select the menu where is your gallery based and do the following:

`Menu manager -> Edit menu item -> Template style` (bottom left dropdown) = you can choose which template you want to use for this menu item.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am still unclear as how it knows to use a php file that has different code in it. For example, if I set my Gallery menu item to Template - Gallery. What is making it different from my default template? Because the change I am making has to do with code in the php file so therefore I have to edit the index.php but if I did so then it would change that for every page wouldnt it?

Comment: Ok, if I understood correctly, you want to duplicate your current template with some minor changes on the index.php to use it for your Gallery? If that is what you want, then simply duplicate it in your templates manager, edit the index.php and then assign it. Why do you need to know how joomla makes the switch? I really think you don't have to go that deep :)

Comment: Well I don't really need to know how it makes the switch.. I just need to know how changing the index.php is going to change only one of the pages when its connected to all of them. If I duplicate the template in template manager it doesn't duplicate the actual template is it supposed to? All it does is gives me a new "Style" but it's still using the EXACT same folder as my original default style so thereofre using the exact same index.php which if I edit.. edits every page.

Comment: you are right! it only creates a new style... the only way that I know is to edit another installed template (delete everything, copy the contents of the template you are trying to edit), then assign to the Gallery...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of.. really seems like they need a better way of handling this.. I wish I could just tell it to use gallery.php instead of index.php on that one page that would solve everything much like how WordPress does it. I believe I saw a possible way of doing by including in the index.php where the code u wanted to take out using if statements if it was on that page to delete this code out, but I don't think you could do it for the gallery probably on like articlepage or frontpage

Answer (score 1):

First it is important to understand how Joomla works. There is only one file in Joomla ever. The framework uses index.php from the current template to create the page being requested. That file basically defines where you can put modules relative to the content that the component is going to display. Joomla knows how to build a page based on the query string of the URL (or variables posted if you have SEF URLs turned on). The URL will tell Joomla what component will be supplying the content, and the itemID of the content.

The component is where the code is different from one page to another. For example, a photo gallery component will have the code to display images while a form component will have the code to display a contact form. Index.php never changes, it just loads the code from the component.

The itemID is the important part of the equation because it is how you can assign different modules to a particular page in the module manager. When you create a menu item for Gallery, it gets assigned a itemID that you can then use to assign various modules or templates to that page. When you create a module (like a login module or menu module) you put it in a position, then assign it to all pages, a selection of pages, of all but a selection of pages.

Generally I don't use multiple templates unless there is a structural difference in the pages. You can just use the page class suffix to assign unique IDs to each menu item so you can then control each page with unique CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your response Brent. The page I am making separate is a structural difference and is not set by a module so I think I will have to use a separate template. It's not a big deal I just wanted to make sure I was doing it the right way instead of just a work-around.

Comment: You should look in to collapsible module positions as well. We build complex sites with very different layouts from one page to another and very rarely have to use more than one template. You can control quite a bit by using the built in menu assignments and the page class suffix. Even layouts that seem structuraly different - like left and right column on one page, then 2 right columns on the next - all within the same template by changing the CSS.